# Content Controls / Form Fields Referencing Other Microsoft Word Documents

Tags: microsoft-word

I wanted to see if it was possible to have the values in a content controls or form fields in one Microsoft Word document can be produced in a different Microsoft Word document. Maybe it isn't through content controls or form fields but I want to see how if this is possible and if so what steps would need to be taken?